# Decimal points handling within textbox in an excel form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I want to display a number in a textbox within an excel form. report, however I only want to show any decimal points if they are present and the I only want to show 2 decimal places.

e.g. if the number is 12 then I want to show 12

If the number is 12.1 then I want to show 12.10

If the number is 12.126 then I want to show 12.13

At the moment i have the below code and it is not showing me decimal points:

```
Me.Amount.Value = Format(Me.Amount, "#,###")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to conditionally return one of two format strings:

```
Function GetFormatString(varValue As Variant) As String
    Dim dblValue As Double
    If IsNumeric(varValue) Then
        dblValue = CDbl(varValue)
        If dblValue = Int(dblValue) Then
            GetFormatString = "#,###"
        Else
            GetFormatString = "#,###.00"
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Amount_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strFormat As String
    strFormat = GetFormatString(Me.Amount.Value)
    Me.Amount.Value = Format(Me.Amount.Value, strFormat)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you phoog, how can i include your code to my existing private Sub Private Sub Amount_AfterUpdate() Me.Amount.Value = Format(Me.Amount.Value, "#,###") End Sub

Comment: I get a complie error. Variable not defined and i think it is referring to "strFormatString"

Comment: I changed strFormatString to strFormat.  issue is that I am seeing a "." at the end of the number... is there a way to not display that "." ?

Comment: What is the value of the number you're using to test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6447/discussion-between-phoog-and-macutan)

Comment: if i type 1000 i would like to show: 1,000
if i type 1000.50 i would like to show: 1,000.50